`count_matches` with multiple options
I have a frame like this:
src = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "c1": ["a", "b", "c", "d"],
        "c2": [[0], [2, 3, 4], [3, 4, 7, 9], [3, 9]],
    }
)

... and a list of targets:
targets = pl.Series([3, 7, 9])

... and I want to count the number of targets in "c2":
dst = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "c1": ["a", "b", "c", "d"],
        "c2": [[0], [2, 3, 4], [3, 4, 7, 9], [3, 9]],
        "match_count": [0, 1, 3, 2],
    }
)

What is the most efficient way to do it?

I see count_matches, but it does not work with multiple options:
df["c"].list.count_matches(3)          # OK.
df["c"].list.count_matches([3, 7, 9])  # No way.


pl.Series([[3, 3]]).list.count_matches(3) returns 2 - do you really want to count matches? Or do you actually want the number of values in both lists? i.e. the length of the set intersection?

@jqurious I don't think there is way to send private messages, but congrats on your second gold!

@jqurious, what I really want is complicated ("rolling-window maximum count of intersections between target and window for each internal list in "c2").
Here I am just exploring my options.

You could use pl.Expr.list.eval to evaluate for each element in the list column, whether it is contained in target. Then, the sum of the boolean list gives the number of matches.
dst.with_columns(
    pl.col("c2").list.eval(pl.element().is_in(targets)).list.sum().alias("res")
)

shape: (4, 4)
┌─────┬─────────────┬─────────────┬─────┐
│ c1  ┆ c2          ┆ match_count ┆ res │
│ --- ┆ ---         ┆ ---         ┆ --- │
│ str ┆ list[i64]   ┆ i64         ┆ u32 │
╞═════╪═════════════╪═════════════╪═════╡
│ a   ┆ [0]         ┆ 0           ┆ 0   │
│ b   ┆ [2, 3, 4]   ┆ 1           ┆ 1   │
│ c   ┆ [3, 4, … 9] ┆ 3           ┆ 3   │
│ d   ┆ [3, 9]      ┆ 2           ┆ 2   │
└─────┴─────────────┴─────────────┴─────┘

Similarly, you could use pl.Expr.list.eval to filter column c2 and, then, use pl.Expr.list.len to see how many values remain. If this is performance critical, I'd suggest benchmarking both approaches.

Alternatively, you are really interested in the number of elements in the set intersection (as mentioned by @jqurious) or the elements in at least one list are unique, you can use pl.Expr.list.set_intersection.
dst.with_columns(
    pl.col("c2")
    .list.set_intersection(targets.to_list())
    .list.len()
    .alias("res_intersection")
)

shape: (4, 4)
┌─────┬─────────────┬─────────────┬──────────────────┐
│ c1  ┆ c2          ┆ match_count ┆ res_intersection │
│ --- ┆ ---         ┆ ---         ┆ ---              │
│ str ┆ list[i64]   ┆ i64         ┆ u32              │
╞═════╪═════════════╪═════════════╪══════════════════╡
│ a   ┆ [0]         ┆ 0           ┆ 0                │
│ b   ┆ [2, 3, 4]   ┆ 1           ┆ 1                │
│ c   ┆ [3, 4, … 9] ┆ 3           ┆ 3                │
│ d   ┆ [3, 9]      ┆ 2           ┆ 2                │
└─────┴─────────────┴─────────────┴──────────────────┘


Thank you. Not what I hoped for, but very informative.
To repeat my answer above, what I really want is complicated ("rolling-window maximum count of intersections between target and window for each internal list in "c2"). Here I am just exploring my options.
The missing piece for me was this: col("c2").list.eval(element(). … ).
I was just trying to formulate a second question along the lines of “How do I fmap leaves of internal Lists inside a Series.”

@KonstantinDruzhkin So, "c2" is given as in the question above, but you actually work with a rolling window (i.e. you have a list of elements of "c2" - a list of lists). For each of the inner lists, you want to count the matches in target (which gives you a window of match counts) and, then, take the maximum across the window?

with your help I have moved to this formulation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78383764/rolling-windows-over-internal-lists

You can use the any() function in Python. Here is a link explaining how this function works. Here is a code I made that may help
import pandas as pd

dst = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "c1": ["a", "b", "c", "d"],
        "c2": [[0], [2, 3, 4], [3, 4, 7, 9], [3, 9]],
        "match_count": [0, 1, 3, 2],
    }
)
targets = pd.Series([3, 7, 9])

count = 0

for i in dst["c2"]:
    # check if any element in i is in targets
    if any(j in i for j in targets):
        count += 1
        
print(count)  # 3

This code iterates over 'c2' and for each target value it checks if the target value is inside the sublists of 'c2'. The in keyword performs a linear search inside all sublists which is O(n). So the whole for loop would make this solution O(n*n) = O(n**2)

Thanks, but this is not what I am looking for. I need it to be fast. And “fast” means multi-threaded and/or vectorized Rust functions, without pythonic for-loops.
