rolling windows over internal Lists
I have a frame like this:
import polars as pl
from polars import Boolean, List, col

src = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "c1": ["a", "b", "c", "d"],
        "c2": [
            [0, 0],
            [0, 1, 0, 0],
            [1, 0, 1, 1, 1],
            [1, 1, 0],
        ],
    },
    schema_overrides={"c2": List(Boolean)},
)

For each of the inner lists in "c2", I am trying to calculate the maximum sum in a sliding window of length 3:
[1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]
⇒
[(1, 0, 0), (0, 0, 1), (0, 1, 1),(1, 1, 1)]
⇒
[1, 1, 2, 3]
⇒
3

What is the most efficient way to do it?

I cannot find the method to roll over inner lists. Several answers on StackOverflow advise me to

explode the inner lists,
roll over the exploded series,
restore the structure somehow.

… which leads to monstrosities like the following:
(
    src.with_row_index("outer_index")
    .explode("c2")
    .with_row_index("inner_index")
    .rolling("inner_index", period="3i", offset="0i", closed="left")
    .agg("outer_index", "c1", col("c2").sum())
    .drop("inner_index")
)

First of all, this is ugly. And this is wrong: rolling windows must respect borders of the original internal lists, but here they do not.
For readability, here is the dump I get with df.to_dicts()
[{'outer_index': [0, 0, 1], 'c1': ['a', 'a', 'b'], 'c2': 0},
 {'outer_index': [0, 1, 1], 'c1': ['a', 'b', 'b'], 'c2': 1},
 {'outer_index': [1, 1, 1], 'c1': ['b', 'b', 'b'], 'c2': 1},
 {'outer_index': [1, 1, 1], 'c1': ['b', 'b', 'b'], 'c2': 1},
 {'outer_index': [1, 1, 2], 'c1': ['b', 'b', 'c'], 'c2': 1},
 {'outer_index': [1, 2, 2], 'c1': ['b', 'c', 'c'], 'c2': 1},
 {'outer_index': [2, 2, 2], 'c1': ['c', 'c', 'c'], 'c2': 2},
 {'outer_index': [2, 2, 2], 'c1': ['c', 'c', 'c'], 'c2': 2},
 {'outer_index': [2, 2, 2], 'c1': ['c', 'c', 'c'], 'c2': 3},
 {'outer_index': [2, 2, 3], 'c1': ['c', 'c', 'd'], 'c2': 3},
 {'outer_index': [2, 3, 3], 'c1': ['c', 'd', 'd'], 'c2': 3},
 {'outer_index': [3, 3, 3], 'c1': ['d', 'd', 'd'], 'c2': 2},
 {'outer_index': [3, 3], 'c1': ['d', 'd'], 'c2': 1},
 {'outer_index': [3], 'c1': ['d'], 'c2': 0}]


You can access .rolling_sum() via the .list.eval() API.
df.with_columns(
   pl.col("c2").list.eval(
      pl.element().rolling_sum(3)
   )
)

shape: (4, 2)
┌─────┬───────────────────────┐
│ c1  ┆ c2                    │
│ --- ┆ ---                   │
│ str ┆ list[i64]             │
╞═════╪═══════════════════════╡
│ a   ┆ [null, null]          │
│ b   ┆ [null, null, 1, 1]    │
│ c   ┆ [null, null, 2, 2, 3] │
│ d   ┆ [null, null, 2]       │
└─────┴───────────────────────┘

And take the .max()
df.with_columns(
   pl.col("c2").list.eval(
      pl.element().rolling_sum(3).max()
   )
)

shape: (4, 2)
┌─────┬───────────┐
│ c1  ┆ c2        │
│ --- ┆ ---       │
│ str ┆ list[i64] │
╞═════╪═══════════╡
│ a   ┆ [null]    │
│ b   ┆ [1]       │
│ c   ┆ [3]       │
│ d   ┆ [2]       │
└─────┴───────────┘


this is a nice one, you can also do .list.eval(...).list.max() to get it to scalar instead. Of course it's possible to get a first (and only) element of list in your solution as well

There remains a little problem. When an internal list is shorter than the window, null comes out, and I have to fall back to summing the full list. (I can fix it with pl.when(...).then(...).otherwise(...) if there is no idiomatic solution.)

You can .fill_null(0) (assuming you want 0 in those cases?)

you can adjust your expression a bit so it would work. You need to add a group_by parameter into DataFrame.rolling() method:
(
    src.with_row_index("outer_index")
    .explode("c2")
    .with_row_index("inner_index")
    .rolling("inner_index", period="3i", offset="0i", closed="left", group_by=['outer_index','c1'])
    .agg(col("c2").sum())
    .drop("inner_index")
    .drop("outer_index")
)

┌─────┬───────────┬─────┐
│ c1  ┆ c2        ┆ s   │
│ --- ┆ ---       ┆ --- │
│ str ┆ list[i64] ┆ i64 │
╞═════╪═══════════╪═════╡
│ a   ┆ [0, 0]    ┆ 0   │
│ a   ┆ [0]       ┆ 0   │
│ b   ┆ [0, 1, 0] ┆ 1   │
│ b   ┆ [1, 0, 0] ┆ 1   │
│ b   ┆ [0, 0]    ┆ 0   │
│ …   ┆ …         ┆ …   │
│ c   ┆ [1, 1]    ┆ 2   │
│ c   ┆ [1]       ┆ 1   │
│ d   ┆ [1, 1, 0] ┆ 2   │
│ d   ┆ [1, 0]    ┆ 1   │
│ d   ┆ [0]       ┆ 0   │
└─────┴───────────┴─────┘

